# What does import * do in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was browsing through [this repo on Github](https://github.com/liuxiaole/2048-react-native) and was trying to comprehend the working of the code

Here, the author (or programmer) have mentioned import * at multiple places so I am trying to comprehend and understand how import * work?

First in [Game.js file of his repo](https://github.com/liuxiaole/2048-react-native/blob/master/src/components/Game.js) he have mentioned/written like this

```
import * as actions from '../actions';
```

In VS Code, when if I click on `'../actions` using command It is redirecting me to this file -> [index.js](https://github.com/liuxiaole/2048-react-native/blob/master/src/actions/index.js)

then in Index.js they have something like this

```
import * as ActionTypes from './action-types';
```

when I click on `./action-types` it redirects me to here [action-types.js](https://github.com/liuxiaole/2048-react-native/blob/master/src/actions/action-types.js)

I went through firefox docs but I wasn't able to clearly make sense for the first example like for one, the action folder contains multiple files and how does import * as actions from '../actions'; mean index.js file

While i get he have called/referenced the functions using `actions.functionName()` or `ActionType.TypeName`

My Prime question remains

how does `import * as actions from '../actions'; mean index.js` file ?

Comment: [It imports an entire module's content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Import_an_entire_module's_contents).

Comment: How "*`'../actions'` mean `index.js` file?*" has nothing to do with the `*` import kind.

Comment: @Tholle I think what's puzzling the OP is that in that source tree, `../actions` from the perspective of that `Game.js` source file refers to an entire directory of JavaScript source files.

Comment: Also, it is important to note that `*` is a common `wildcard` character when doing searches or queries. It just matches everything. In this case, you are importing everything that matches `*` from the `../actions` file. So, just everything from the file. I'm also guessing `../actions` is the lazy way of writing `../actions.js`

Answer (score 7):

The `import * as name` syntax imports all exported content of a javascript file.

> For example, if you want to import an entire module's contents, then access the `doAllTheAmazingThings()` function
>
> ```
> import * as myModule from '/modules/my-module.js';
> myModule.doAllTheAmazingThings();
> ```

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Answer (score 4):

`Import` in js is new syntax of ES6 to import a module it has the same work of `require` but its easier to filter what do you want in a module

In your example you `import * as actions from '../actions';` you import all function from `../actions` file

its same to do `const actions = require('../actions')`

but its easier to manage what you want

this syntax is not work on all browser so be sure to use transpiler with babel or other

you can see this syntax in python too

Answer (score 0):

When you reference a directory in an import statement, it looks and loads the index.js file in that directory. What I usually do there is export classes and functions under that directory in a grouped object, so they can be easily accessed:

For instance in index.js I export sth like:

```
{
    Class1,
    method1
}
```

where each is imported as such:

```
import Class1 from './Class1';
```

So they just group the classes/methods/... that are in files in the directory.

Then you can easily access it as such:

```
import { Class1, method1 } from './mymodule';
```

vs

```
import Class1 from './mymodule/Class1';
```